# Replace continues occurrences of string using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have string which contains some repeated properties which I have to replace with one occurrence like follows:

I have String

```
".lf-form-container{font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;background-color:rgb(217,217,217) !important;}"
```

and I wanted to make it

```
".lf-form-container{font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;background-color:rgb(217,217,217) !important;}"
```

by using javascript can any one help me in this.

Comment: There is `.replace()` function for that

Comment: How it generated?, maybe you could prevent to duplicating

Comment: Actually this string I have in the css which I dynamically adding to the header but I want to filter this repetition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```js
var str = "font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;background-color:rgb(217,217,217) !important;";

var arrStr = str.split(";");

var uniq = arrStr.reduce(function(a,b){
 if (a.indexOf(b) < 0 ) a.push(b);
 return a;
  },[]);

console.log(uniq.join(";"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var string = ".lf-form-container{font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;background-color:rgb(217,217,217) !important;}",
    declarations = string.match(/\{(.+)\}/)[1];

string = string.replace(declarations, [...new Set(declarations.split(";"))].join(";"));
```

This works by splitting the string around the semicolons, filtering the resulting array for unique values via usage of `Set`, and joining it with semicolons again. Note that this is not a general solution for removing duplicate substrings; it will only work for semicolon-delimited duplicates.

If ES6 is not available, here is an ES5 solution:

```
string = string.replace(declarations, declarations.split(";").filter(function(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}).join(";"));
```

Comment: Hey, Hydrothermal thanks for your reply but I have a string like which I have just edited can you please help in this?

Comment: @FIROZTENNALI You can first regex out the text inside the curly braces then put it back together after removing the duplicates. I've edited my answer to show how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Considering all properties combined with `;` you can use string `.split()` and `.join()` method to achieve the desired result;

```
var demo = "font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;background-color:rgb(217,217,217) !important;"

var res = str_text.split(';').filter(function(item,i,allItems){
                             return i==allItems.indexOf(item);
                     }).join(';');
```

```js
var demo = "font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;background-color:rgb(217,217,217) !important;"

var res=demo.split(';').filter(function(item,i,allItems){
    return i==allItems.indexOf(item);
}).join(';');

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this `string` as `array` by `split` and remove duplicated array like this:

```js
var string = "font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;background-color:rgb(217,217,217) !important;";

var array = string.split(';');

var result = [];
$.each(array, function(i, el) {
  if ($.inArray(el, result) === -1) result.push(el);
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to **retain only first occurrence of the property** so try this approach

```js
var input = "font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;background-color:rgb(217,217,217) !important;";

function retainOnlyFirstOccurence(input) {
  var propMap = input.split(";").reduce(function(a, b) {
    if (b.length == 0) return a;
    var splitB = b.split(":");
    if (typeof a == "object") {
      if (!a[splitB[0].trim()]) {
        a[splitB[0].trim()] = splitB[1];
      }
    } else {
      var splitA = a.split(":");
      var splitb = b.split(":");
      a = {};
      if (!a[splitA[0].trim()]) {
        a[splitA[0].trim()] = splitA[1];
      }
      if (!a[splitB[0].trim()]) {
        a[splitB[0].trim()] = splitB[1];
      }
    }
    return a;
  });
  return Object.keys( propMap ).map( function( key ){
    return key + ":" + propMap[ key ];
  }).join( ";" );
};

console.log( retainOnlyFirstOccurence( input ) );
```

Logic

- `split` by ; to get all key values
- `reduce` to get a `proMap` which doesn't overwrite the properties.
- `map` to again convert `propMap` to key values
- `join` to join all key values by ;